# LWC Quick Actions in Experience Builder

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud

From Summer '21 LWC component can be used as a Quick action, after I added it into the record page layout that works in the Lightning page, but it does not show in the Experience Builder.

Is there a way to use the LWC Quick action in the Experience cloud?

Comment: Are you able to add other Quick Actions or just LWC? Could you please check if it is the same page layout assigned for both profiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the recent [release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232) that delivered this feature

> Where: This change applies to Lightning Experience desktop in
> Developer, Enterprise, Essentials, Professional, and Unlimited
> editions. **Quick actions aren’t available in Experience Cloud sites**.

Just to confirm, I then created an object page with a record banner component and verified that the LWC quick action did not appear (although a quick action calling aura component does).

[image]

It seems, as of right now, the **answer is no**. You'd have to utilize an aura component that wraps your LWC.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Is there a way use the Aura to replace a actionType is Action LWC quick action? We don't want to show a modal when a user click a quick action

Comment: Are you asking if you can do headless actions with Aura? Unfortunately, that's only through LWC. With aura, you could look at some workarounds from previous [questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229905/lighting-action-to-only-call-apex?noredirect=1&lq=1) where you just display a spinner and then close the component yourself.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @Kris

Answer (score 0):

Now LWC Quick actions are supported in Experience Builder as well. Not sure in which release this change is done.But if we specify the community target types in the meta file we can do this.